# When I git merge <branch>, sublime text opens

Tags: git, sublimetext

I do not have a core.editor set in my git config. I am not sure how to stop sublime from opening, it used to deal with merge msgs/conflicts in vi, I would like to get that functionality back. I just updated to git 2.0 today.

*edit: I just checked and it also does it when I git commit without including a message argument, which is what I have been doing, which is probably why I didn't notice until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `git config --global core.editor vim` and you should go back to your old git 1.X behavior. I don't know all the internals of git 2 yet, but probably what happened is you have the `EDITOR` environment variable set to `subl`, and in the absence of `core.editor` Git fell back to using that. The old version may have used vim by default, or it was set in `/etc/gitconfig` or someplace, but the behavior changed with the new version.

Comment: this fixed my problem twofold, vim is now set as the default editor for git, and I found the environment variable in a dot file I recently installed (should have read that one more carefully)